# Jersey and Jackson serialization of subclasses does not include extra attributes

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

In Jersey, when using Jackson for JSON serialization, the extra attributes of an implementing subclass are not included.  For example, given the following class structure

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Foo.class, name = "foo")
}
public abstract class FooBase {
    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar( String bar ) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

public class Foo extends FooBase {
    private String biz;

    public String getBiz() {
        return biz;
    }

    public void setBiz( String biz ) {
        this.biz = biz;
    }
}
```

And the following Jersey code

```
@GET
public FooBase get() {
   return new Foo();
}
```

I get back the following json

```
{"@class" => "foo", "bar" => null}
```

But what I actually want is

```
{"@class" => "foo", "bar" => null, "biz" => null}
```

Also, in my web.xml I have enabled POJOMappingFeature [to solve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899397/jsontypeinfo-does-not-serialize-when-using-jackson-with-jersey)

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Edit: Fixed the Java code to have the setters set properly and Foo to not be abstract

Comment: Is the Foo class def really abstract?

Comment: FWIW Using just Jackson (without Jersey), the example serializes as expected as {"@class":"foo","biz":null,"bar":null}

Comment: Fixed the abstract Foo problem

Comment: Programmer Bruce - yeah - I found that too, if I use straight object mapper it serializer properly - or if I return Object it serializes properly - it is only if I use the abstract class as the return type that it does not serialize properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work as you show; with one possible exception: if you enable JAXB annotations (only), JAXB restrictions mandate that only getter/setter pairs are used to detect properties.
So try adding setter for 'biz' and see if that changes it.

This would not occur with Jackson annotations; and ideally not if you combine Jackson and JAXB annotations (I thought Jersey enabled both).
If Jackson annotation processing is also enabled, adding @JsonProperty next to 'getBiz' should also do the trick.

Finally unless you need JAXB annotations, you could just revert to using Jackson annotations only -- in my opinion, the main use case for JAXB annotations is if you need to produce both XML and JSON, and use JAXB (via Jersey) for XML. Otherwise they aren't useful with JSON.

Comment: Doh - sorry, when making the example - I messed up the code trying to make it simpler (should have been setBiz)

Comment: I thought it was the abstract class that was causing the problem - I think it is a generics issue (the abstract class has a parameter in the real code) - I'll put together a full example sometime soon.

Comment: Yes -- Java type erasure can throw a wrench; since the only generics that survive are ones in field/method declaration, and super type declaration. In-code things are just implicit casts and not available during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Using `POJOMappingFeature` you can also annotate your classes with JAXB:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class FooBase {
    private String bar;
}

@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo extends FooBase {
    private String biz;
}
```