# Jersey Jackson does not serialize subclass

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am creating a RESTful service using Jersey. To return the result I need to convert to JSON format. I have a parent and child class where only parent class values are sent but child class is not getting serialized.

Parent Class -

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class)})
public abstract class Parent {
    private String test = "hello";

    public Parent () {
    }
    public Parent (String test) {
     this.test = test;
    }
    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }    
    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
```

Child Class -

```
public class Child extends Parent{
   private String name;

   public Child() {
       super();
   }
   public Contact(String name, String test) {
      super(test);
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }    
   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Actual Class -

```
public class RestResponse {
    private List<Parent> result;
    // default and one argument constructor...

    public List<Parent> getResult() {
        return result;
    }    
    public void setResult(List<Parent> result) {
        this.result= result;
    }
}
```

Rest Controller -

```java
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/testJson")
public class MyRestController {

  

      @GET
      @Path("/search")
     public RestResponse getContacts(@Context HttpHeaders headers) throws URISyntaxException {
       Parent p = new Child("myName", "testString");
       List<Parent> parentList = new ArrayList<Parent>();
       parentList.add(p);
       RestResponse resultResponse = new RestResponse();
       resultResponse .setData(parentList );
       return resultResponse; 
}
```

But below is the result I get,

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "test": "testString"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where the subclass's property name is not serialized. I tried the solution given in [Jersey and Jackson serialization of subclasses does not include extra attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374421/jersey-and-jackson-serialization-of-subclasses-does-not-include-extra-attributes), but still I see subclass properties are not getting converted.

Comment: it is not possible to see subclass fields when sending a `Parent` object, you need to send a `Child` object to see both the `Parent` object properties and the `Child` properties. The child object has the properties of the parent not the opposite

Comment: I know, some time ago.. anyhow...
I usually put those annotations you have in your parent class ( `JsonSubTypes` `JsonTypeInfo` ) into my response object - in your case the `RestResponse` - just above `private List<Parent> result;` - this way it works for me